# Database connection not permanent saving

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, connection

I am using visual basic express 2010, and i have made a connection to a database i made. When i use the program, on first hand nothing seems wrong i can see the data i put in my database using the program and the data is also in my database itself but when i close visual basic and look at my database a few day's later all of my previous data is gone, so to put it simple my data doesn't save permanently. And now i know this is because i use dataset which is an offline database connection. and now my question is can i change my code so that when i click 'save' my data is actually saved in my database and doesn't disappear in a few day's? My code(some things are in dutch sorry bout that):

```
Public Class KlantToevoegen

Private Sub KlantBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles KlantBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click

    If TbGemeente.Text = ""
    Or TbPostcode.Text = ""
    Or TbAdres.Text = ""
    Or TbVoornaam.Text = ""
    Or TbNaam.Text = ""
  Then
    MsgBox("Update failed!")
Else
    Me.Validate()
    Me.KlantBindingSource.EndEdit()
    Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.PowerShotKassaBonDataSet)
    MsgBox("Update successful")
End If
End Sub

Private Sub KlantToevoegen_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

Me.KlantTableAdapter.Fill(Me.PowerShotKassaBonDataSet.Klant)
End Sub

Private Sub TbGemeente_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TbGemeente.TextChanged

    If TbGemeente.Text = ""
Then
    Me.ErrInvullen.SetError(Me.TbGemeente, " Geef de gemeente in. ")
Else
    Me.ErrInvullen.SetError(Me.TbGemeente, "")
End If
End Sub

Private Sub TbPostcode_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TbPostcode.TextChanged

    If Not IsNumeric(Me.TbPostcode.Text) Then
    Me.ErrInvullen.SetError(Me.TbPostcode, " Geef een (correct) postcode in. ")
    TbPostcode.Text = ""
Else
    Me.ErrInvullen.SetError(Me.TbPostcode, "")
End If

    If TbPostcode.Text.ToString.Length > 4 Then
    TbPostcode.Text = ""
    Me.ErrInvullen.SetError(Me.TbPostcode, " Geef een correct postcode. ")
    MsgBox("Geef een correct postcode in.")
End If
End Sub

Private Sub TbAdres_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TbAdres.TextChanged

    If TbAdres.Text = ""
Then
    Me.ErrInvullen.SetError(Me.TbAdres, " Geef het address in. ")
Else
    Me.ErrInvullen.SetError(Me.TbAdres, "")
End If
End Sub

Private Sub TbVoornaam_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TbVoornaam.TextChanged

    If TbVoornaam.Text = ""
    Or IsNumeric(Me.TbVoornaam.Text) Then
    Me.ErrInvullen.SetError(Me.TbVoornaam, " Geef een Voornaam in. ")
Else
    Me.ErrInvullen.SetError(Me.TbVoornaam, "")
End If
End Sub

Private Sub TbNaam_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TbNaam.TextChanged


    If TbNaam.Text = ""
    Or IsNumeric(Me.TbNaam.Text) Then
    Me.ErrInvullen.SetError(Me.TbNaam, " Geef een naam in. ")
Else
    Me.ErrInvullen.SetError(Me.TbNaam, "")
End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: do you committ your transactions?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258243%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

Comment: If i read it right this is for sql and i don't have sql in my code so not sure how to implement this in my code.